# Bootstrap grid system rows in row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying make some grid in bootstrap and I do not know whether I'm coming correctly so here is my HTML:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row bg-white">

        <div style="background-color: #0a4d85" class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #00B312">
                <p>text</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="background-color: #0000BB" class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row"> <!-- This row -->
                <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #0c0c0c">
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #00a1e8">
                    <p>text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result from this code is like this (no padding for right side):
[image]
But if I remove "row" class (selected in HTML comment) result is as i expected:
[image]

So how? I am doing something wrong or row in row is bad practise?

Comment: You shouldn't put a row in a row, just put the columns straight in.

Comment: and your inner row is a grid of 24 columns so you might wanna look at that also

Comment: You have this `<div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #00B312">` nested directly inside of `col-md-6`, Remove the first nested 12 Columns and you'll see the difference  See [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap grid is based on a 12 column layout. There are three major components containers, rows, and columns. Rows are horizontal groups of columns that ensure your columns are lined up properly. Hence, `Row in row is not good practice`. `Column classes indicate the number of columns you’d like to use out of the possible 12 per row.` So if you want three equal-width columns, you’d use `.col-md-4`.

Comment: _row in row is not good practice_ This is not wholly true. Nesting is completely valid as the framework itself takes this into consideration. See the Bootstrap Docs: [Nesting columns](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting).